# How can I retrieve data from a database where start balance and end balance are correct using PHP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am running against the problem below.

In my database I have a table that looks like this:
[image]

Displaying the table is fine.

Column5 indicates whether Column4 contains a negative or positive number. C = positive and D = negative.

Column1 is the balance before column4 has been pulled off. You can say, opening balance.

Column2 is the balance after column 4 has been pulled off. you can say, final balance.

Example of top two lines is at this time:

95.00 + 181.00 = 276,00 (Column4, positive)

1894.65 + 276.00 = 2170.65 (result is in Column2, this is also the beginning of the next line Column1).

What I want is as follows, adding or subtracting starting from oldest date:

1894.65 + 95 = 1989.65 (line 1)

1989.65 + 181.00 = 2170.65 (line 2)

2170.65 – 40.00 = 2130.65 (line 3)

2130.65 + 1001.92 = 3132.57 (line 4)

etc.

I can not do this because in Column1 the same number occurs as it was executed on the same date (Column6).

I tried them with different if then options but result is not what I want.

who could help me in this or push me in the right direction

I hope I have described it clearly. I use PHP and PDO

Comment: The table structure seems like a mess. This sounds like a mysql question only. There is no issue with implementing in PHP/PDO right?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query